# Как заменить произвольный текст на значение переменной в файле формата txt с помощью python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, автоматизация

Необходимо, чтобы случайный текст который находится в файле txt был заменен на значение переменной, после чего изменения в файле были сохранены, важным является то, чтобы по завершению замены файл имел то же название.

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time

pyautogui.click(1308, 50)
time.sleep (2)
pyautogui.doubleClick(707, 87)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
input = (pyperclip.paste())
id_now = (input)
with open('id last.txt', 'r') as file:
   id_last = file.read().replace('\n', '')

if id_now != id_last:
   with open ('id last.txt', 'r') as f:
     old_data = f.read()

   new_data = old_data.replace( '', id_now)

   with open ('id last.txt', 'w') as f:
     f.write(new_data)
```

главной проблемой данного примера является то, что когда в файле нет никакой информации оно без проблем ее заменяет на значение переменной, однако если в файле уже есть текст оно его дублирует около 10 раз, а необходимо чтобы оно полностью заменило имеющийся текст длиной около 15 символов на текст с переменой примерно такой же длины

Comment: Последние 2 строки, вне контекста Вашего кода, прекрасно отрабатывают, вне зависимости от содержимого файла. Я хотел проанализировать Ваш код, но Вы не проставили отступы, он не валиден. Я (и не только) не могу ставить их наугад, пожалуйста, отформатируйте вопрос правильно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Отредактировать отступления так как они в файле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в инструкции `new_data = old_data.replace('', id_now)`.

`replace('', ...)` вставит текст и в начале, и в конце, и между каждым символом исходного текста. Скорее всего, это не то, что Вы хотели.

> Просто замените эту инструкцию на `new_data = id_now`.

***P. S.:***
Ваш код довольно неоптимизирован, вот хороший пример:

```py
id_now = 'Some text...'

with open('id last.txt', 'r+') as f:
    id_last = f.read().rstrip()

    if not id_now == id_last:     
        new_data = id_now

        f.seek(0)
        f.write(new_data)
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Недавно начал изучать python 3 это мой первый проект. Надеюсь со временем улучшу свой код)